# How to execute Spark programs with Dynamic Resource Allocation?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am using spark-summit command for executing Spark jobs with parameters such as:

```
spark-submit --master yarn-cluster --driver-cores 2 \
 --driver-memory 2G --num-executors 10 \
 --executor-cores 5 --executor-memory 2G \
 --class com.spark.sql.jdbc.SparkDFtoOracle2 \
 Spark-hive-sql-Dataframe-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Now i want to execute the same program using Spark's Dynamic Resource allocation. Could you please help with the usage of Dynamic Resource Allocation in executing Spark programs.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In Spark dynamic allocation `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled` needs to be set to `true` because it's `false` by default.

This requires `spark.shuffle.service.enabled` to be set to `true`, as spark application is running on YARN. Check this [link to start the shuffle service on each NodeManager in YARN](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#configuration-and-setup).

The following configurations are also relevant:

```
spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors, 
spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors, and 
spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors
```

These options can be configured to Spark application in 3 ways

**1. From Spark submit with `--conf <prop_name>=<prop_value>`**

```
spark-submit --master yarn-cluster \
    --driver-cores 2 \
    --driver-memory 2G \
    --num-executors 10 \
    --executor-cores 5 \
    --executor-memory 2G \
    --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=5 \
    --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=30 \
    --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors=10 \ # same as --num-executors 10
    --class com.spark.sql.jdbc.SparkDFtoOracle2 \
    Spark-hive-sql-Dataframe-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

**2. Inside Spark program with `SparkConf`**

Set the properties in `SparkConf` then create `SparkSession` or `SparkContext` with it

```
val conf: SparkConf = new SparkConf()
conf.set("spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors", "5");
conf.set("spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors", "30");
conf.set("spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors", "10");
.....
```

**3. `spark-defaults.conf` usually located in `$SPARK_HOME/conf/`**

Place the same configurations in `spark-defaults.conf` to apply for all spark applications if no configuration is passed from command-line as well as code.

[Spark - Dynamic Allocation Confs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#dynamic-allocation)

Comment: In my cluster spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled is true. Do i need to do any thing programmatic ally to use this feature. what should be the Spark-submit command ?

Comment: No need. specifying maximum executors will be fine as mentioned any of above places.

Comment: @mrsrinivas it is told now with spark 2.x Dynamic allocation no longer needed/supported ? Can you please advice?

Comment: @user3252097: I don't find anything like that, can you share me the reference?

Comment: why you did you set num-executors=5 ? you have already set spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors and spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors executor via conf.

Comment: not both, any one is fine. `num-executors` in shell == `spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors` via conf

Comment: @mrsrinivas what if I only set spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors and spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors? Do I also need to set spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled to True?

Comment: yes, `spark.dynamicAllocation.{min/max}Executors`is relavent only if `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true`. which means those configurations will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a small demo with Spark's dynamic resource allocation. The code is on my [Github](https://github.com/avinash0161/spark-dyn-res-alloc). Specifically, the demo is in [this release](https://github.com/avinash0161/spark-dyn-res-alloc/releases/tag/dyn-res-alloc-localMachine).