# How can I tune a spark job in real-time?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

How can I tune memory core consumption during spark structured streaming job in pyspark?

Answer (score 1):

You can only tuned a job in spark before submit phase.

You can tune a spark job this way:

```
  ./bin/spark-submit \
  --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
  --master spark://207.184.161.138:7077 \
  --executor-memory 20G \
  --total-executor-cores 100 \
  /path/to/examples.jar \
  1000
```

Comment: No no when the job is waiting for a new task (in standby mode) or if I want to reduce the executor-memory in spark job to use that memory in other job, how can I decrease the executor-memory and  total-executor-cores .

Comment: @OzanDikerler it's exactly what i'm trying to say. The tuning in a spark can only be made on the submit phase. But you can use dynamic allocation (only recommended for streaming jobs as your case). Dynamic allocation allows Spark to dynamically scale the cluster resources allocated to your application based on the workload.  You can see this thread on stack overflow https://stackoverflow.com/a/40200504/10900556